# Is it faster to query records using $wpdb instead of Wp_Query?

Tags: wp-query

I mean the speed of query records from database, not the way we render the content gained.
More specifically, I just want to query the posts' IDs, my site contains more than 4000 posts (they are custom post type) and I just want to have all their ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, custom SQL queries are in essence faster than a custom instance of `WP_Query`. The disadvantage of a custom SQL query is that you are loosing a lot, like object cache, filters and actions, etc, etc, and it is also discouraged to use custom SQL if Wordpress already offers that specific functionality.

`WP_Query` does have the option however to only query post ID's (*which is really fast and very lean*) by means of adding and using the `fields` parameter in your query arguments. You can also just use `get_posts` which uses `WP_Query` but does not return the post object but just the array of posts

So, you can basically do the following

```
$args = [
    'nopaging' => true,
    'fields' => 'ids' // Just get post ID's
];
$q = get_posts( $args );
var_dump( $q );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to cache a custom SQL.

```
     function get_sample_data() {
        global $wpdb;

        $query
            = "
            SELECT  ID ,post_title
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
            WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'sample_type'
            AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_sample_meta_key'
            AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'singular'
            ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date ASC
            ";

        $result = wp_cache_get( 'sample_cache_key' );
        if ( false === $result ) {
            $result = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
            wp_cache_set( 'sample_cache_key', $result );
        }

        return $result;
    }
```